# Distribution Directory in TexnicCenter not accepted

Tags: texniccenter, directory

I am using MikiTex 20.11 (the latest version downloaded today) on my Windows 10 machine with TeXnicCenter 2.02 and I want to do the basic setup procedure, only it is not accepting the standard distribution directory[image]. The subdirectories I have are [image]

How can I fix this issue? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't look only on the pictures of the folder, look what is *inside*. The binaries are in `miktex\bin\x64` not in `miktex\bin`.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer